# How to use datepicker with custom format

Tags: excel, vba

I'm try to get from the user the date and time at the same datepicker so I try to do 21/06/2019 23:38 this format(dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm)

I use with Microsoft Date and Time Picker control version 6.0

```
public Sub bTNOK_Click()
Cells(1,1).Value = Format(DTPicker1.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm")
End Sub

public Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With DTPicker1
.Format = dtpCustom
.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"
End With

End Sub
```

on the properties of datepicker

CustomFormat ["dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"]

Format [3 - dtpCustom)

Value [21/06/2019]

when I run this the Value of cell 1,1 is "30/12/1889 00:00" so how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't have that installed so I can't play with it, but this probably won't work:  `.Format = dtpCustom`.  You'd probably want to put quotes around the `dtpCustom` part.  `dtpCustom` is being handled as a variable in your code, not a string or a name.

Comment: Also, why are you formatting within the date picker, then again formatting the output of the date picker?  It seems like once should do it.

Comment: So you think that I need to use with regular text? Because I wnat the user will know the format that I want and always stay like this. So I try to use with datepicker with date and time.

Comment: I would recommend doing everything in discrete steps so that you understand the outputs fully.  It could be that you're assuming incorrectly what is happening in each step.

Comment: What do you mean only what I want is get from the user date and time at the same editext or not together and I want to get like this 26/06/2019 00:59

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
public Sub bTNOK_Click()
  Cells(1,1).Value = Format(DTPicker1.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm")
End Sub
```

to this:

```
public Sub bTNOK_Click()
  Cells(1,1).Value = Format(DTPicker1.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm")
  Cells(2,1).Value = DTPicker1.Value
End Sub
```

Tell me what happens.

Comment: return 12:00:00 am

Comment: This should tell you that DTPicker1 isn't accepting the value being given to it, or the date is being parsed out.  It is only returning the default value.  12:00 am is like zero.  It might also be that .Value isn't where the date is stored once you enter it.  You'll have to dig around.

Comment: The value that I write is: 27/06/2019 23:20

Comment: OK, but it doesn't look like it's being stored in DTPicker1.Value.  Keep in mind the cell formatting, too.  I think that the default formatting for a datetime value will only show the time of day in the cell, but if you click into the cell the true value will be represented.